# Python parsing GPRMC string with CSV

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I have GPRMC string which consists of 12 comma delimited values. When I run my code it does in fact split the commas, but it prints each character in the comma separated value on a new line - instead of grouping all characters in between a comma together.

For example:

```
>>> gprmc = "$GPRMC,1244.0,A,3111.334505,N,90729.3111898,W,1.2,,020811,,,A*55"
>>> gprmcReader = csv.reader(gprmc)
>>> for val in gprmcReader:
    print val


['$']
['G']
['P']
['R']
['M']
['C']
['', '']
['1']
['2']
['4']
['4']
['.']
['0']
['', '']
['A']
['', '']
['3']
['1']
['1']
['1']
['.']
['3']
['3']
['4']
['5']
['0']
['5']
['', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'r'))

for row in reader:
    if row and row[0].strip() == '$GPRMC':
        for val in row:
             print val
        print "_____________________"
```

To check my code i have created file that contains one row with the following text:

```
$GPRMC,135005.0,A,3526.351705,N,90729.337898,W,1.2,,020811,,,A*55
```

Executing my code prints me:

```
$GPRMC
135005.0
A
3526.351705
N
90729.337898
W
1.2

020811


A*55
```

Comment: I don't care about stripping GPRMC. I just want all characters in the in between each comma to be grouped together

Comment: What do you mean on grouping could you please update your question to show us what you really want since my code gives me the output you mentioned in your question

Comment: @danes - i have added one more check on empty row to sample

Comment: @danes - first parameter for reader is an iterable - so my code works pretty well with files since open(...) returns an iterator to file lines, however if it is required to parse string(but i can see why do you need this) like in your sample you can use 'csv.reader([gprmc])'

Comment: Please learn the standard lib.  Instead of hacking a one-line data file, using StringIO to return a file-like object wrapper around a string.